# Unit Testing Parsers Written Using FParsec

Tags: unit-testing, fparsec

I'd like to write unit tests for abstract syntax trees generated by a parser that I write using FParsec.

For instance, given the parser

```f#
 open FParsec

 type FooValue = FooValue of int
 let foo: Parser<string,unit> = pstring "foo" 
 let fooValue = pint32
 let p = foo >>. spaces >>. fooValue |>> FooValue.FooValue
```

the only testing way I found so far was writing

```f#
let resultSuccess = run p "foo 23"
let resultFailure = run p "foo noNumber"

printfn "%O" resultSuccess
printfn "%O" resultFailure
```

and checking if my F# program outputs

```
Success: FooValue 23
Failure:
Error in Ln: 1 Col: 5
foo noNumber
    ^
Expecting: integer number (32-bit, signed)
```

Instead, I'd prefer to write some unit tests like these:

```f#
open FParsec
open Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

[<TestClass>]
type TestMyParser () =

    [<TestMethod>]
    member this.TestPSucceeds () =
        let actual = run p "foo 23"
        let expected = ......? 
        Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);

    [<TestMethod>]
    member this.TestPFails () =
        let actual = run p "foo noNumber"
        let expected = ......? 
        Assert.AreEqual(actual, expected);
```

As you can see, I have no clue how to construct valid functions for expected values of the abstract syntax trees of FParsec so I could somehow compare them with the actual result of each test I run.

***Edit***: It would help me also (and probably simplify the comparison of more complex ASTs a lot) if I could somehow serialize the actual results to strings and just compare them to expected strings.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do it, it is relatively simple using `sprintf`. The TestMethod could look like this:

```
    [<TestMethod>]
    member this.TestPSucceeds () =
        let result = run p "foo 23"
        let actual = sprintf "%O" result
        let expected = """Success: FooValue 23""".Replace("\r","")
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Enclosing the expected string in `"""`, followed by the `Replace("\r","")` function makes sure that you can also paste more complex, multi-line parser output here.